# QGIS 2.14.5.LTR Gdal-Tools execution problem

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, osgeo4w

I have installed QGIS 2.14.5.LTR via the OSGeo4W installer on Windows2008R2. No raster tools are available. After activating Gdal-Tools plugin, the raster tools are available, but cannot executed (because Gdal-Paths are not set?):

[image]

In the dialog under menu `Raster > GdalTool-Settings...` the paths to GdalTools can be set but `C:\OSGeo4W\bin` where these modules reside (`gdalbuildvrt.exe` e.g.) has no effect.

[image]

On the other hand, GdalTools via the processing toolbox can be executed without any problem:

[image]

I have no idea wether here is something wrong with my path settings or if it is an issue with the OSGeo4W installer. Any Ideas?

Comment: Under Windows (any version) there is no need to set any path regarding the so called "gdal tools". I believe that if that dialog shows then you have some kind of installation problem. Try also removing the .qgis2 folder and start QGIS again, maybe you have some old stuff in there.

Comment: tried to remove the .qgis2 folder, no effect. Added some additional info, cp. above.

Comment: Does it work if you copy the command line, and execute it in a batch file insdide the OSGEO4W shell?

Comment: If the gdal/ogr based tools are running ok in the Processing toolbox then it means the gdal/ogr installation that comes with QGIS is ok as also the paths. This issue is then some weird problem with the core plugin "gdal tools". I would suggest making a clean installation, this means also removing the QGIS registry keys after uninstalling the software.